# How to print only the trace of custom exception? Instead TestNG Trace

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, testng

```
class use extends Test {

    @org.testng.annotations.Test
    public void test() throws exc {
        try {
            System.out.println("test");
            int a = 1 / 0;
            System.out.println(a);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            throw new exc("This is EXC error");
        }
    }       

class exc extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public exc(String a) {
        super(a);
    }
}
```

---

1. I want to print only 1st two lines in the console
2. Able to do that if I execute from Main Method, but using TestNG throws extra trace as shown.

---

This is the Console

```
FAILED: test

runner.exc: This is EXC error
    at runner.use.test(Test.java:47)
```

---

### I want to print upto here, but consoles shows the below too

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to get the first thwo lines as a string:

```
// tr is the exception object
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
tr.printStackTrace(pw); // Replace tr with your exception object
String[] stl = sw.toString().split("\n");

// Get the first two lines
// Use deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1) to get rid of \r at the end of the line (You may not need to this)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (stl.length > 0) sb.append(stl[0]).deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1).append('\n');
if (stl.length > 1) sb.append(stl[1]).deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1).append('\n');

// Use sb.toString() to get the result
```

Comment: You can simply use `StackTraceElement[] ste= e.getStackTrace();` And print first two elements.

Comment: almost true, but printStackTrace will add a "\tat " before every element and its first line will include the error message itself, which is not included in getStackTrace();

Comment: ... except that that you don't know *in general* how many elements to print!

Comment: what do you mean by that @Stephen C (do you refer to "onkar ruikar" or me)

Comment: I mean onkar - where he says "and print the first two elements".

Comment: ohh ok. got it!